# How to update the second or much later data in mongo with UpdateOne method?

Tags: mongodb

I'm in a trouble. I want to update the second item in a sorted doc in mongo. But the UpdateOne can't use skip in the filter param. I know the aggreate operation cant do it with skip and merge. However, how to use UpdateOne to realize it?

```js
the data:
[
    {"_id":1, "name": "tramp"},
    {"_id":2, "name": "Biden"},
    ...
]
```

How to update them _id equal to 2, 3, and others?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Even so, I'm not entirely clear about your query. **I hope you'll find what you're looking for here.**

```
const { data } = req.body;
data.forEach(async (e) => {
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: e._id }, { name: e.name});
})
```

**User** is your Collection Name